# import invoices (multiple lines) into quickbooks desktop premiere version

Tags: .net, excel, import, quickbooks, invoice

i have quickbooks desktop premiere version. i need to import invoices (multiple lines) into QB . I dont want to use any paid third party tool. Please let me know the best solution possible. Also , what should be the correct excel format that can be imported successfully.
 thanks

Comment: possible answer http://blog.baystateconsulting.com/index.php/2010/11/29/how-to-import-multi-lined-transactions-into-quickbooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple lined transactions if you do not want to use any third party tools your only option is IIF files read more in the article below.

https://help.quickbooks.intuit.com/en_US/kb/import-kit/HOW12778